# Deploy UWP automatically on debug but not on build

Tags: deployment, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

UWP applications under Windows 10 must be deployed before they can be run/debugged.

Visual Studio 2017 offers an option to disable deployment of a project on build:

[image]

This allows one to build a solution and check for compilation errors (e.g. `ctrl+shift+b`)  without needing to wait several seconds (even on a machine with 64GB of RAM and an MLC or 3D XPoint SSD) for the deploy to go through.

However, the problem here is that attempting to debug the application (e.g. F5) will run the last-deployed version of the project, which is undesirable.

Is there an easy way to set the debug target for the project such that it is deployed on first debug (as is currently the case), subsequent debugs without changes to the build do not trigger an unnecessary deploy (which is the default, out-of-the-box behavior), but *builds* do not directly trigger a deploy?

Comment: Not sure about that, but you can right-click in Solution Explorer and "Deploy" the app at any time. That might not meet your needs though.